Azure Function App Kudu Functions API with empty response
I'm deploying a Function App with https://my-function-app.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy, I managed to retrieve the Location Response Header to check the deployment provisioningState and ensure is Succeeded.
Now I need to check if at least one function was deployed into the Function App. I'm checking this URL https://my-function-app.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions but every time is answering an empty array, event with at least one function in Enabled state.
Is there another way to do the same verification ?
Thanks in advance

You could ask the Azure Resource Manager API directly instead of Kudu.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-functions?view=rest-appservice-2024-04-01
There might be an option also via the Azure CLI/PowerShell - have a look at the documentation if you don't need an API options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/function?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-function-show
Speaking about deployment, any special requirement why you use kudu?
I'd recommend you to use the Function Core Tools https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-azure-functionapp-publish
func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME>
Which also have an option to return the functions within the function app
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-azure-functionapp-list-functions
func azure functionapp list-functions <APP_NAME>

Hi Julian thanks for the reply. list-functions worked as we expected. But publish I'm not sure.
We have a pipeline which package the source code as docker containers and deploys as Container Apps, and the deployment is done with them.
I'm working in a alternative solution to enable Function Apps in our environment, but in the deployment phase I don't have access to the source code to deploy it using "publish", I can only access the docker files. Is there a way to "publish" be done with a zip file ? I can generate a docker image with it, and a shell script to be run inside it.

I discovered the options "--source ./my-function-app.zip --verbose --no-build " and worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for the enlightenment !

Great, are all your question answered then? Please do not forget to mark this as answered ;-)
